# Creating a table with chosen parameter as table title SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My current code is shown below (doesn't work). I would like to create a table with the its title as cor_@dt with @dt being the chosen date paramter (in this case 8/14/2013)

```
USE [dWA_NSCC]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- exec [CORP\Eng].[No_Indx] '8/14/2013', '1'
ALTER PROCEDURE [CORP\Eng].[No_Indx]
    (@dt datetime, @numb int)
AS
BEGIN

DROP TABLE @dt
CREATE TABLE @dt
(
ticker varchar(50),
no_indx_cusip varchar(50),
benchmark_cusip varchar(50),
maxcor decimal(10,5),
regcoef decimal(10,5),
dt_pnts int
)


 ... some more code
```

Comment: Which begs the obvious question..Why are you trying to create tables with a DATE in their name? (this is usually a red flag for poor database design).

Comment: You really want to create a table named `8/14/2013`? Why, why, why?

Comment: or maybe convert it to an int its because im running this query everyday to create a new table so i would like to know what date the table is created

Comment: Why are you creating a new table every day, and why is the table named for the date? What does it contain?

Comment: something like 8142013.cor

Comment: it contains correlation data that is to be used for daily stress tests

Comment: @euge1220, Don't create a table every day. Add an INSERT_DATE column and store all the data in a single table.

Comment: Don't listen to the haters. This is a really good idea 8}

Comment: @JustinKirk I hope you have to support this application some day ;)

Comment: We should be able to specify a different font color when employing sarcasm.

Comment: apologies for committing a class A programmatic felony

Answer (score 7):

Well, forgetting for a moment that this smells really, really bad, this code will create a table called `08/14/2013.cor`. Note that in all code that references it, because it starts with a number *and* contains bad characters, you'll have to use `[square brackets]` around the name.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @dt, 101) + '.cor') 
  + '
  (
    ticker varchar(50),
    ...
  );';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

A much better design would be to have a single table with an additional column (perhaps serving as the clustered index) and then you can just insert your stress test information for a certain day, and queries for that day can come from the same table as queries for another day.

Comment: @Declan_K you can only talk so much sense into people. Sometimes this is just the requirement and they're not able to fight it, either.

Comment: @Declan_K also I'd rather have an answer that explains the work-around but also explains the dangers, than just answers that explain the work-around. Which do you think is more "encouraging"? Which do you think is better for other readers?

Comment: i'll take your advice with the additional columns. i'm not a programmer i just need to use SQL sometimes for information compliation

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
CREATE TABLE _temp (
    -- Columns here
)
EXEC sp_rename _temp, @newtablename
```

With this you can set `@newtablename` to whatever you want.